# Gaussian Process Proofs and Results

Tags: convergence, gaussian-process, proof

I am building a model based on Gaussian processes and want to assume something like as my sample size $n$ gets large my prediction error goes to 0.  In other words,a re there any proofs or theorems out there that show something like

$$Pr((\hat y -y)=0)\rightarrow1$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? Here $\hat y$ is my predicted value and $y$ is my true value.

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. As $n \rightarrow \infty$ your inference about the model (hyper)parameters will become more accurate. Not your actual predictions. If you have noisy data, well... you have noisy data, you will not be able to predict them accurately unless you overfit (which is wrong).

Comment: [_Regularity dependence of the rate of convergence of the learning curve for Gaussian process regression_](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2879) shows convergence of one measure of error in a standard GP regression setup.

Comment: @Dougal, Nice paper (+1) but this IMSE is not what the OP is asking for. You are talking about the BLUP, the OP is asking for his predictions error converging to zero.

Comment: @Dougal, I did not mean to imply it was not useful; if anything I upvoted the comment. I do not want the OP to misread it as an indirect proof for what it is originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot assume that as your sample size $n \rightarrow \infty$ your prediction error will tend to zero.

Your prediction error $(\hat{y} -y)$ will never tend to zero. This is true in *any* statistical model that uses data that might be noisy irrespective of the dataset's sample size. Your only change is that the data are truly noiseless and therefore you will correctly infer that the noise variability is of zero magnitude and then your prediction error will also become zero (assuming your model models the true underlying dynamics). What you can expect is, that with larger sample size, your (hyper)-parameters $\hat{\theta}$ will become closer and closer your true $\theta$. This is true for any [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_%28statistics%29) estimation procedure. As a standard reference on the subject I would suggest you look at Chapter 7 from the [Gaussian Process for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/book) by Rasmussen and Williams. Section 7.2 on the asymptotic analysis of GPs is most probably what you need;the section's extensive reference list will point you to specific papers if you need to dig a particular matter further.

Comment: Do the person that down-voted this care to explain why?

Comment: I think someone just trolled the page - you can get a +1 from me ;)

Comment: I returned the favour. :D

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $y = f(x) + \epsilon$, as said in the comments the best we can do is to model $f(x)$ with $\bar{f}(x)$ and it seems that you want $\bar{f}(x)$ to approach $f(x)$with the limit of data. This will only happen with some kernels. If the kernel is degenerate, such as a linear kernel, then it can only model a subset of functions, such as linear functions. This means that even in the limit of data we will not be able to model the true $f(x)$. If we use a squared exponential kernel (as an example) then we can model all functions. The proof is simple just let the length scale tend to zero as data comes in.

One nicety is that as a kernel puts a probability mass over the function space, if $f(x)$ lies outside the space of functions which a kernel defines, then in the limit of data $\bar{f}(x)$ tends to the function which minimises the KL Divergence between $f(x)$ and $\bar{f}(x)$.

Comment: The -1 here is undeserved. Can the downvoter please explain why he treated this as not useful?